# How can I check in QGIS python if an atrribute is included in my layer?

Tags: qgis, python, layers

I use the following code:

```
for field in self.layer.pendingFields(): 
    if field.name()=='elevation':
        do this
    else:
        do that
```

Although there is an elevation attribute in my layer it does not recognize it does that instead of this.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you add the output of `[f.name() for f in layer.pendingFields()]`

Comment: a little more information on what `this` and `that` do is necessary also.  It could be that you are doing `this`, and then later `that` is overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is calling either this or that for every single field in the attribute table. That might mess things up. Instead try

```
field_names = [field.name() for field in self.layer.pendingFields()]
if 'elevation' in field_names:
   do this
else:
   do that
```

Comment: Normally the provider fields are the same as the layer fields. They just differ if you added or removed fields between the last `startEditing()` and the next `commitChanges()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MatthiasKuhn! Seems like both the function name choice and the description in the documentation don't really help to understand what this function is about.

Comment: Then you will be happy to see that just a couple of hours ago I have [changed the API doc for this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/5be0ee734fa233f2a3f893ddc72e8264d029f2d0#diff-a6e96a0b4b80e4889dfcc03ec2bd4731R804) and my plan is to alias `pendingFields()` with `fields()`.